# find repeated characters in a list

Tags: f#

I have a situation in finding a sequence of **strings** that have patterns like `XXXX` or `CCCC` or "`IIII`". I have tried the following code, but it does not work

```
    let rec checkSequence roman=
       let r=List.ofSeq  roman
       match r with
       | [] -> true   
       | a::b::c::d::tail   when  (a="I" || a="X" || a="C") && a=b && a=c && a=d   -> false
       | head::tail                                                             -> checkSequence tail


checkSequence "CCC"
```

The error is: `This expression was expected to have type string list but here has type string`

1-How can I resolve this error?

2-Is there any simpler way to find this patterns?

Comment: As an aside from the question ; you could have used the literal directly in the pattern : `| ("I"|"X"|"C"as a)::b::c::d::_ when a=b &&a=c && a=d -> //...` Another point is the string converted to list will give you a `char list`` not a `string list` (because string is a `char seq`) so technically those literal should be char literal not string ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need use a recursion on list you may do something like this:

```
let checkSequenceStr str =
    let rec checkSequence roman =
        match roman with
        | [] -> true   
        | 'I'::'I'::'I'::'I'::tail -> false
        | 'X'::'X'::'X'::'X'::tail -> false
        | 'C'::'C'::'C'::'C'::tail -> false
        | head::tail  -> checkSequence tail
    checkSequence (str |> List.ofSeq)
```

Or you could use .NET string methods to check patterns directly (which is easier):

```
let checkPattern (str : string) =
    ["IIII";"CCCC";"XXXX"] |> List.exists str.Contains |> not
```

Comment: Maybe better to use (not) Contains instead of IndexOf = -1 and a slight refactor too : `let checkPattern (str : string) = ["IIII";"CCCC";"XXXX"] |> List.forall (str.Contains >> not)` or alternatively `let checkPattern (str : string) = ["IIII";"CCCC";"XXXX"] |> List.exists str.Contains |> not`

Comment: Yes, that's better. Corrected answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `List.ofSeq`, this will type force the roman parameter to be of an type list.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340325.aspx

Therefor your error `This expression was expected to have type string list but here has type string` is due to calling the function wrongly, then an logical error. Therefor change:

```
checkSequence "CCC"
```

Into:

```
checkSequence ["C"; "C";"C"]
```

Comment: That' more the inconsistency between `List.ofSeq roman` which implies roman is some `seq` (and string is a seq) and `checkSequence tail` with tail, some list which cause the problem